# locationchangestart prevention in ngDialog

Tags: angularjs

I have used `locationchangestart` to prevent `dialog` close on clicking backspace key. It is working commonly for all dialogs. So it won't work for path change while closing the dialog. How can I restrict this? I need to change the `$location.path` when I close the dialog. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If your model is like

```
$scope.closeLoginModal = function () {
        $location.path("/myhome");
        });
          };
```